# GitHub on Azure continuos deployment failure

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to implement the continuous integration with Azure & GitHub for one of my project , during the deployment phase we are seeing Thread was being aborted error.

Comment: Can you post the error and what your are doing exactly (some code)?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details (such as the specific error, what steps you went through to get the error, etc). Also, please clarify whether this is with Web Apps (I'm assuming so, given the use of github, but wanted to be sure, since you didn't tag it).

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the response.Below is the error what am getting and am follwoing the steps mentioned in the URL .https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftimagine/2015/09/01/using-continuous-integration-with-azure-github/

Comment: Error: Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\tree\master\cloud\src\solution\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.sln" /nologo /verbosity:m /p:deployOnBuild=True;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false;publishUrl="D:\local\Temp\8d3a5eae334d644"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\56.50630.2306\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"